# I can not convert my ajax from "GET" to "POST"

Tags: ajax

```
 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

function ajaxFunction(){
  var ajaxRequest;  

  try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert('Your browser broke!');
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('pagecomments');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;

    }
  }
  var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
  var queryString = '?message=' + message + '&wpm=' + wpm;
  request.open("POST", ajaxprofilechat.php, true);  
  http.send(null); 

  }

  </script>
```

Hi, I am trying to convert this script that I have from the ajax GET method to POST method, as I think that it will solve one of the problems that I am having on my website.  However, I am very, very novice in ajax coding and although I have attempted to convert to POST, there is an error because this script is not working.  Could someone who is good with ajax please help me fix this problem that I have?  All I want this to do is to work using the POST method.  Do I even need to use variable and query strings when using POST?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time!

Here is ajaxprofilechat

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$age = $_POST['message'];
$wpm = $_POST['wpm'];
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age); 
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
$chatname6 = ($_SESSION['username']);
$message6 = $_GET['site_message'];
$month6 = date("F");
$dayofmonth6 = date("d");
$year6 = date("Y");
$date10 = "$month6 $dayofmonth6 $year6";
$hours6 = date("g");
  $min6 = date("i");
 $sec6 = date("s");
 $amorpm6 = date("A");
 $time6 = "$hours6:$min6 $amorpm6";

 if (strlen($age)>4)
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES        ('','$wpm','$chatname6','$age','$date10','$time6')");
echo "&nbsp;<h80><b>Comment Posted</b></h80><p><p>";
}
else
 {
 echo "&nbsp;<h80><b>Your comment must be greater than four characters</b></h80><p>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You should start by learning about ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Gus said correct the ajaxprofilechat.php .

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'ajaxprofilechat.php', true);
```

plz you note you are using different ajax objects each time , you have to stick with the object  ajaxRequest .

then make sure you send your params  this way :

```
var params= 'message=' + message + '&wpm=' + wpm;
  ajaxRequest.open("POST", 'ajaxprofilechat.php', true);  
  ajaxRequest.send(params);
```

also add this line before the send

```
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

also try to make things simple to make sure everything is working  use hard coded values in the first time :

```
var message = 'test';
  var wpm = 'test';
```

also use chrome developper tools or firebug  to see errors details , 
hope this helps

Comment: Thank you guys so much for the help.  So this part is now great, but I think that they might be an error on my ajaxprofilechat.php page.  If you would not mind could you look at that too please?

Comment: I just posted ajaxprofilechat.  That is the error though Flame, when I run ajaxprofilechat using POST, these two variables $age=POST['message']; and $wpm = $_POST['wpm']; are not getting a value, so the rest of the code can not run.  That is where I am stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see what I mean, go to http://pearlsquirrel.com/login.php and login with the username and password guest.  Then go to the top right corner of the page and click on the word that says page.  On your page, scroll down and that textbox is area where this code should be executing and telling you whether or not your post is less than 4 characters and if you it is successful, it will send a success message.  However, none of this is occurring and no data is being inserted into the database

Comment: Thanks, I just added it, but I still have the same error; nothing is happening.  So idk what to do now...

Comment: you made some mistakes in your javascript you should use the object ajaxRequest  all the way .  check my edit .

Comment: i tested the ajax part with some minimal php like   $age = $_POST['message'];
$wpm = $_POST['wpm'];

echo $age;
echo $wpm;

all worked fine  , do the same thing to eliminate doubtful code chunks gradually

Comment: Thanks!  I will implement these tonight, and then I'm going to go to bed.  If i have any more trouble, when I get back from school tomorrow I will post another message here.  I really do appreciate all of the help!

Comment: Dude everything now works flawlessly.  I can not tell you how ecstatic I am.  I tried to solve this for hours upon hours.  Thank you so much.  If there is anything that I can do to help you, like uping your rating or even filling out a survey I would be happy to.  I will also make sure to bookmark you page in case I ever need help again.  Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I have encountered one more error.  Now when I press enter, the line breaks are inserted, but when I am just typing in the textbox and it starts a new line, those are not inserted.  Is there an easy way to fix this?  I assume that it is a quick fix, I am just not able to see it.

Comment: i believe it's a new problem , but here's a tip for it , use str_replace in Php to remove the line breaks and replace 'em with whatever u like 
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);

Comment: Hmmm.  I tried that, but it does not seem to fix the problem.  I have also been looking on google and other people say the same this as well, however nothing works in my case.  I guess I am just a very novice coder, lol.

Comment: When I press enter, the line breaks are inserted, but when I am just typing in the textbox and it starts a new line, those are not inserted. I did exactly what you told em to do, but it did not fix the problem.  And thank you for helping me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: and you want to remove those line breaks ??  because it's normal to have 'em inserted with the text .
the question is , how do you want to replace the line breaks ??
here's a useful method   http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding me.  When you press enter, it inserts a break and it works.  But, when you get to the end of the line and it starts the new one fore you, there should be a break inserted at that exact point on the end of the line, but there is not.  Like when typing in this textbox you do not press enter and it starts a new line for you.  You dont have to press enter and a break is inserted.  For some reason, in my textbox no breaks are being inserted at the end on lines and I need them to be.  I am already using nl2br.

Comment: I have fixed the problem.  Thank you so much for all of you assistance Frozen!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes around the url:

```
request.open("POST", 'ajaxprofilechat.php', true);
```

Without them, javascript is looking for the variable `ajaxprofilechat` with property `php`.